# How would a smart person think if they were constantly duplicating themself then having one clone kill the other like in Prestige?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind

In real life, I would actually be against it. They would be letting the other clone really suffer. However, my point is theoretically what could happen. In Prestige, the guy who kept cloning himself eventually at the end they showed it from the point of view of the clone who got shot by the other clone. Then while he was dying, he said it took a lot of courage not knowing whether he would be the clone who lives or the clone who dies.

My question is

> If a smart person was constantly duplicating themself in such a way that one clone would die but not right away and it would be so obvious to them that they're going to die, would they continue being 50% sure they're going to be the clone that dies this time even after having done it a billions times and remembering having been the one that survives every single one of those times?

You may be thinking if you were 50% sure every time that you would be the clone who dies and it never happened any of those billion times, you would be really incredibly lucky so another theory must be true. But think about it this way. You are technically living in the moment. Memories of the past and visions of the future are technically a property of what's flooding your brain right then. You can treat it like yourself in different short patches of time is a different soul.

Take a related thought experiment. There are 2 people in a game. One continues the game. The other gets kicked out and it's random. Then later we have a different pair of people. Each of them learns things only about the person from the previous pair that ended up staying and has only 4 hours to learn things about after which they will cease contact with them indefinitely. Then after that, it's randomly picked which one goes and which one stays. Then both people from the next pair learn things only about the one that ended up staying. If you were in the 54th pair and you learned things about the one from the previous pair that ended up staying but hadn't yet found out whether you are going to stay or go, would you be 50% sure that you were going to be the one who ends up going? Probably. Because you know that it has happened before. You just didn't learn things about the people that it ended up happening to. But they would be some kind of structure in the flow of the game almost a though the people earlier on in the game are a past branch of you. However you probably wouldn't feel like it was really your past. When I learned about events that happened in our universe billions of years ago, I didn't feel like the distant past of our universe was my past and instead felt like it was a new experience of mine.

In The Legend of Zelda: Breath of the Wild, there is an old woman with plum trees. You can destroy them. She speaks as though they're going to be gone for ever but you can come back and they're back and can destroy them again and get that initial impressions again. Although I stopped playing Breath of the Wild 3 years ago, looking back on it and imagining myself doing it again nd again, I see that my brain adapts to be like the initial impressions is a present experience of itself that has no real meaning of how the future is actually going to go. However, you can still speak as though they're going to be gone for ever this time.

I guess that similarly a person who was constantly doing that duplicating stunt would feel like they're never actually going to be the clone who dies but understand speak as though they're going to be the one who dies this time. It's like talk of the future is now thought of as being a present experience.

Comment: "You can treat it like yourself in different short patches of time is a different soul" this is contrary to our everyday experience. Who gets a headache today when you got drunk yesterday ? Who feels ready for the test when you studied last week ? I bet you always experience the personal consequences of your past actions first hand, not as if it happens to someone else.

Comment: The way the question is passed is about psychology, not philosophy, though it's probably unsuitable to any Stackexchange site due to being opinion based, too broad, and unclear

Comment: I think I made this into an XY question. I wasn't thinking. A lot of this belongs as an answer rather than part of the body of the question.